# Javascript throws an "is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working with Javascript and recently I've been stucked with an error which I can't solve.

The Firefox console throws an "info[last] is undefined" error, and I've got no idea what is causing that. Here is the code, the line which provokes the trouble is number 7:

```
$("textarea").each(function() {
var id = $(this).parents("div.article").attr('id').split('_')[1],
    kind = $(this).attr("class"),
    text = $(this).val(),
    last = info.length-1;

    if(last !== 0) {

        if(info[last].id == id) {
            info[last].info.push([kind, text]);

        }

    } else {

        object = {
            id: id,
            info: [[kind, text]]
        };

    }

    info.push(object);
});
```

Hope you guys can help me figure it out.

Comment: What happens in 'info' has zero element in it? Where is 'info' defined?

Comment: Haven't seen !== before, are you sure it's valid ? (Compared to !=)
Edit: R. Hill is right, if info has 0 elements, you do a info[-1].id == id...
Change the last !== check to last > 0

Comment: Steffen: !== is strict !=, it doesn't do type conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$("textarea").each(function() {
var id = $(this).parents("div.article").attr('id').split('_')[1],
    kind = $(this).attr("class"),
    text = $(this).val(),
    last = info.length-1;

    if(last >= 0) {
       //Check the index exists before accessing it - incase its null or similiar..
       //Strictly speaking, we should test for the properties before we access them also.
       if(info[last]) { 
         if(info[last].id == id) {
            info[last].info.push([kind, text]);

        }
      }

    } else {

        object = {
            id: id,
            info: [[kind, text]]
        };
        info.push(object); //Also move this up.

    }


});
```

I've moved a few things around, and changed the check for valid 'last'.  Otherwise I've also added an if to double check that an object exists at that point in the array before trying to access it's properties.

Answer (score 1):

If `info` is empty, `last` will be `-1`.

Change your `if` to

```
if(last !== -1) {
```

Also, you probably want to move

```
info.push(object);
```

inside the `else`.

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.